# How do I pass values from a specific row on a DataGrid as a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I would like all values on a specific row passed to a new form.  I know how to extract the values, but how should I pass these values into the new form (each will be assigned to a specific textbox)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to hide the rest of the DataGridView from the new form?  For instance if you pass a DataGridViewRow to the form the new form can get the values directly.  But that would also give them access to the DataGridView.

```
DataGridViewRow dgr = dataGridView.Rows[0];
MyForm myForm = new MyForm(dgr);  // now the form has the Row of information. But it can also access the entire DataGridView as it is available in the DataGridViewRow.
```

If you want to remove access to the DataGridView then place the values in the row into a container and pass that container.  You could use something built in like an ArrayList, List, etc.. or create your own custom container.

Comment: +1 I set it up as an Array list at first but wasnt sure if that was the optimal solution.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class that has a property for each column in your dataset.  Then you can use a list of your class to store everything, and each element of the list would be a row.  You can then set your `DataGridView.DataSource = yourList`.  When you need to pass a column along, just pass through that element of the list.

If you really don't need to make a class for your data, you could also just pass a [DataGridViewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx) to your function.

Comment: +1: Agreed, just keep in mind that if passing the DataGridViewRow, the entire DataGridView is given to the new form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?  Do you mean if I simply pass in dataGridView.Rows[i] as an argument, instead of assigning it to a new variable?  I could see that passing in a reference to the row, but not the whole grid.

Comment: If you do new MyForm(dataGridView.Rows[0]); the new form will have the DataGridViewRow. It can then access the entire DataGridView through the DataGridViewRow.DataGridView property.  Assigning it to a new variable as I showed above does that same thing.

Comment: I should clarity that passing the DataGridViewRow doesn't explicitly pass the DataGridView.  It only exposes the DataGridView.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  My advice was meant to be the same as what you gave (pass in a copy of the DataGridViewRow).  I guess I didn't express that very well though.  Thanks for pointing that out to me.